# How to remove a about:config entry on Firefox?

Tags: firefox, about-config

When trying to activate Webgl on Firefox, I misspelled "Webgl" and wrote "Weblg".

I tried to remove it from about:config with delete key or seeing right mouse click options on it, but without success...

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Googling about, I found [that solution](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t9891-delete-entry-from-about-config.html):

> Close Firefox. Backup the prefs.js file located in your profile
>   folder. Open the original prefs.js in a text editor. Remove erroneous
>   key, and save.
>
> -- Brian

Answer (score 0):

Simply reset the entry that you want to delete in about:config and then restart firefox et Voilà !

I don't know how long this solution will remain valid but it works fine at least for now...

Comment: It doesn't work as of at least Firefox 59. (I initially though that it was)

Comment: @TUXAYO,can you precise ,please, what was the behaviour of firefox ?

Comment: If I recall correctly, the key was still there with an empty value.